# Sending the same command to multiple TCP clients with separate IPs and the same port

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I'm not very well versed in any scripting languages, but I have been asked to create a software solution for live replay using the Blackmagic Hyperdeck (if anyone knows what that is) that can accept a series of predefined commands over TCP. I decided to start this task in Pythion, only because it is what I know best I researched the documentation for socket, but I need to send the command out to three different "servers". They all operate off of different ips, but have the same port. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You say you "researched the documentation for socket" which describes and contains examples of sending data to a server. Now just repeat that three times to connect to three different servers.

Comment: The `selector module` has some fun examples for you in petto.

Comment: Hi James, I need to send the message at exactly the same time due to timecodes